# addEventListener is not a function?

Tags: javascript

chrome gives me errors like that:

[image]

i don't know why and i already define the function adEventListener in my javascript code.Errors like this:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://news.sohu.com/20151120/n427408363.shtml?ajax=true. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

```js
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Ajax Connection Queue</title>
    <script src="utils.js"></script>
    <script src="queue.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
     function addEvent(to, type, fn){
      if(document.addEventListener){
          to.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
      } else if(document.attachEvent){
          to.attachEvent('on'+type, fn);
      } else {
          to['on'+type] = fn;
      }  
  };
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      addEvent(window, 'load', function() {
        // Implementation.
        var q = new DED.Queue;
        q.setRetryCount(5);
        q.setTimeout(3000);

        var items = $('items');
        var results = $('results');
        var queue = $('queue-items');

        // Keeping track of my own requests as a client.
        var requests = [];

        // Notifier for each request that is being flushed.
        q.onFlush.subscribe(function(data) {
          results.innerHTML = data;
          requests.shift();
          queue.innerHTML = requests.toString();
        });
        // Notifier for any failures.
        q.onFailure.subscribe(function() {
          results.innerHTML += ' <span style="color:red;">Connection Error!</span>';
        });
        // Notifier of the completion of the flush.
        q.onComplete.subscribe(function() {
          results.innerHTML += ' <span style="color:green;">Completed!</span>';
        });
        var actionDispatcher = function(element) {
          switch (element) {
            case 'flush':
              q.flush();
              break;
            case 'dequeue':
              q.dequeue();
              requests.pop();
              queue.innerHTML = requests.toString();
              break;
            case 'pause':
              q.pause();
              break;
            case 'clear':
              q.clear();
              requests = [];
              queue.innerHTML = '';
              break;
          }
        };
                
        var addRequest = function(request) {
          var data = request.split('-')[1];
          q.add({
            method: 'GET',
            uri: 'bridge-connection-queue.php?ajax=true&s='+data,
            params: null
          });
          requests.push(data);
          queue.innerHTML = requests.toString();
        };
        addEvent(items, 'click', function(e) {
          var e = e || window.event;
          var src = e.target || e.srcElement;
          try {
            e.preventDefault();
          }
          catch (ex) {
            e.returnValue = false;
          }
          actionDispatcher(src.id);
        });

        var adders = $('adders');
        addEvent(adders, 'click', function(e) {
          var e = e || window.event;
          var src = e.target || e.srcElement;
          try {
            e.preventDefault();
          }
          catch (ex) {
            e.returnValue = false;
          }
          addRequest(src.id);
        });
      });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
      body { font: 100% georgia,times,serif; }
      h1, h2 { font-weight: normal; }
      #queue-items { height: 1.5em; }
      #add-stuff {
        padding: .5em;
        background: #ddd;
        border: 1px solid #bbb;
      }
      #results-area { padding: .5em;border: 1px solid #bbb; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body id="example">
    <div id="doc">
      <h1>Ajax Connection Queue</h1>
      <div id="queue-items"></div>
      <div id="add-stuff">
        <h2>Add Requests to Queue</h2>
        <ul id="adders">
          <li><a href="#" id="action-01">Add "01" to Queue</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" id="action-02">Add "02" to Queue</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" id="action-03">Add "03" to Queue</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <h2>Other Queue Actions</h2>
      <ul id='items'>
        <li><a href="#" id="flush">Flush</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="dequeue">Dequeue</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="pause">Pause</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="clear">Clear</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id="results-area">
        <h2>Results: </h2>
        <div id="results"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: your addEventListener problem stems from things like `var items = $('items');` in your code ... what is `$`? if it returns anything other than a single html element, you can't addEventListener to it in the line `addEvent(items, 'click', function` for instance

Comment: You have jQuery available, so why you're only using it to select elements (which doesn't work at all as the selectors don't match anything)? All this mess with events respectively repeated code could be simplified... -> [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 0):

mate, it's not your problem, it's the server does not allow the resource to be used on your website, unless you can contact the owner, adding your sites/ip to their Access Control Allow Origin on the web server response header,  then you can access it